# Class function is not found

Tags: python, django, pinax

I have the problem with creation of Referral from pinax-referrals package. Referral class has class function create(...) When I am trying to create referral inside view like:

```
from pinax.referrals.models import Referral

def createReferral(user):

    referral = Referral.create(
        user = user,
        redirect_to = "/"
    )
```

It throws me following error:

> type object 'Referral' has no attribute 'create'

The code inside Pinax model looks ok:

```
@classmethod
def create(cls, redirect_to, user=None, label="", target=None):
    if target:
        obj, _ = cls.objects.get_or_create(
            user=user,
            redirect_to=redirect_to,
            label=label,
            target_content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(target),
            target_object_id=target.pk
        )
    else:
        obj, _ = cls.objects.get_or_create(
            user=user,
            label=label,
            redirect_to=redirect_to,
        )

    return obj
```

As I understand the problem is not connected to the Pinax package itself and looks really strange. Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Can you show your imports?

Comment: I just edited the question.. import are ok too from pinax.referrals.models import Referral,ReferralResponse

Comment: The import and `createReferral` method that you have posted look ok. Is there anything else in the module that could have overwritten `Referral`? Have you defined another class `Referral`. Are you doing `from x import *` in the module?

Comment: Can you create referral via shell?

Comment: @Alasdair yes, the only one import which probably can influence is my own model ReferralCompetition. I have tried to comment it but it didn't help. Also I don't have any other classes with the same name. Do you mean from pinax.referrals.model import * ?

Comment: @AlexLisovoy yes, I can create referral via shell.

Comment: @Alasdair ok..got it with import *. I am not doing any global imports.

Comment: I thought you might be doing `from <other_module> import *`, which could be replacing your `Referral` class with another one. What does adding `print(Referral)` at the beginning of your `createReferral` method show?

Comment: @Alasdair I found the cause of the problem. Inside my views I have declared a class based view with Referral name. Thank you very much! You idea with print inside the view helped a lot!

Comment: Great :) I've added it as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have defined another class `Referral` inside the same module, that has replaced Pinax's `Referral` model.

This could happen because you have defined a class,

```
class Referral(View):
    ...
```

or maybe you have imported another class `Referral`. It might not be obvious this has happened if you do a `*` import.

```
from mymodule import *
```

A useful tool to debug is to add `print(Referral)` to you view. Then you will see whether the `Referral` class is the one you expect.